# T-SQL - Update long list of values based on long list of ids

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkupdate

It may seem as a straight forward task, but I can't really find a good approach.

I have a long list of ids with a long list of corresponding values to update for a field (a single field)

```
id = 1 | field = value_1 
id = 2 | field = value_2
.......................
id = n | field = value_n
```

I can put the fields in 2 lists (or any other way i choose to) but i have to loop through and update each value..

What would be the best approach for this?

To add few more details: The values are in a big excel, but this is not about processing that excel, I will copy paste the list of values into.. text. I was thinking 2 long list (id1, id2,..)    (value_1, value_2,...)

Comment: What client do you use for this porpose? Where that data for update comes from?

Comment: what would be the final result

Comment: I usually write a python script to generate this kind of sql then copy-paste-run.

Comment: if i understood correctly, you have data and wish to convert it to sql code. if so, use excel's concatenate function and wrap your data with sql parts. then copy/paste and execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one time job, convert the text into a CSV or other format that is processable by bcp.exe, then import it into a temp table, do the update via a JOIN, then drop the temp table.

For a repeatable job I would us [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx): [flat file source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139941.aspx) the data or even directly [Excel source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx), [source the table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx), [merge the two sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141703.aspx), apply the result [back into the table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is a good method, but for completeness: when this is a one-time task, and the updates all follow a simple pattern like that, it can also be effective to convert the input text directly into a series of update statements, using an Excel formula and fill down or using a text editor's replace function.

Example:

```
id     newvalue
1      foo
2      grok
```

becomes

```
id     newvalue    generated statement
1      foo         update dbo.mytable set field1 = 'foo'  where id = 1
2      grok        update dbo.mytable set field1 = 'grok' where id = 2
```

Quick and dirty, but apply with care and watch out for unexpected syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

is what i did in the end, I created a temp table, I imported all the values in it and updated via a join